# How to manage secrets of Kubernets object execpt Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

This question might be silly but I am struggling to find out.

I am creating a ServiceAccount Object and passing an Annotation that has sensitive information, and I don't want to explicitly provide that information on the manifest also don't want to keep it on a repository.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: velero-service-account
  annotations:
      eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: "arn:aws:iam::111111111:role/eks-velero-backup"
```

Here, I am considering `11111111` as the sensitive information.

I am planning instead of `111111111` this value I have to place a variable and store it in the repo and have to store the actual value somewhere else.

when I deploy, the actual value should be placed on the intended location.

I am using EKS Cluster and kubectl utility.

If someone has a solution for this please comment below.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

*Something* fundamentally must substitute this value and send it to the Kubernetes cluster.  It will always be readable in plain text by `kubectl get serviceaccount velero-service-account -o yaml`.  That may affect how much you're willing to obscure the value.

If you're using Helm, this could be a simple delpoy-time substitution:

```yaml
# templates/serviceaccount.yaml
metadata:
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: "arn:aws:iam::{{ .Values.awsAccountId }}:role/eks-velero-backup"
```

Then when you go to deploy it, your deployment system can substitute the value

```bash
helm upgrade --install release-name . \
  --set-string awsAccountId=123456789012
```

or put the value in a YAML or JSON file that's supplied by to the `helm upgrade -f` option.

Helm will store this value in a Secret in the cluster, and again `helm get values release-name` will show the actual value.

Comment: This one is really good and yes, I'll use this as a Helm chart deployment, but what if I am using AgroCD for deployment?

Is this approach suitable for the ArgoCD Deployment?

My actual plan is to keep the Velero Helm Chart on GitHub and Deployment will be through ArgoCD.